# Can't resolve services by name in Openshift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I followed this [link](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-openshift-origin-on-ubuntu-18-04/) to install openshift v3 on ubuntu everything works fine, I have two services like this which are pointing to deployment containers. They work fine when I use their ips.

```
NAME       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
test1   ClusterIP   172.30.98.103    <none>        5055/TCP   22m
test2   ClusterIP   172.30.156.106   <none>        5555/TCP   23m
```

but my pods cannot resolve service names, I did not have this problem while using cloud openshift services and as I have read openshift has a built-in dns server ([Link](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/architecture/additional_concepts/networking.html)). Maybe I'm missing something?
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: If you're just starting out with openshift I would suggest v4 instead of v3.

Comment: @larsks well only v3 is free and v4 is commercial I think

Comment: @ArmanMomeni OKD (= old OpenShift origin..) is free: https://docs.okd.io/latest/welcome/index.html   https://www.okd.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, for anyone reaching here, when I installed openshift after I searched on the internet when my build-configs couldn't pull from github I followed this [post](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/issues/5249#issuecomment-659559682) which added dns to both nodes and kubedns, after I sshed into pods and checked the /etc/resolv.conf file I figured out the `8.8.8.8` would come prior to `172.30.0.2` which was causing the service name not to be resolved. Remove the `"dnsIP" : "8.8.8.8"` from `openshift.local.clusterup/node/node-config.yml` if you've added it or find a way to put it below `172.30.0.2` and problem will be solved.